# Setting up a callback handler for HTTP requests (Twitch API) with TCL

Tags: api, http, callback, tcl, twitch

I'd really like some help setting up something with TCL that I can get HTTP requests from Twitch's API (I think they send HTTP POST requests). I'd like to do this within an IRC bot or a Discord bot that I already have running.

I've looked a bit into it already and it seems like this might be possible with websockets, but I'm not experienced enough with it and there's not a ton of stuff on this with TCL since I get the feeling the language is not so prevalent anymore.

If anyone could help me out with some code examples or explaining how to do this in a simple way that'd be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

To receive an HTTP POST, you need to stand up a server. There are a few options, but one of the simplest is [tclhttpd](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tclhttpd/). It's old, but works, and there's a [reference](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tclhttpd/reference.html) and an [online book chapter](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tclhttpd/TCLHTTPD.html) that say how to use it. They're a little bit tricky to grasp.

For what you're doing, I'd guess that you'd want to a direct domain:

```
# Route the handling of messages to http://$host:$port/incoming to the procedure below
# as a *directly processed* URL, which is the most flexible approach
Direct_Url /incoming HandlePost

proc HandlePost {args} {
    # Override the content type from the default of text/html
    global HandlePost/msg
    set HandlePost/msg "text/plain"

    # Do stuff with the arguments to make the result document
    set result ""
    set index 0
    foreach {key value} $args {
        append result "Argument #[incr index]: $key ==> $value\n"
    }
    append result "\nOK\n"
    return $result
}
```

Put that in a file that is in a directory used as a library directory by tclhttpd (I find that's easiest by setting the `-library` option on the tclhttpd command line) and that should be enough. You'll also need to make the code produce the right response and do the right things when it gets the message when you POST.

It's probably easiest to experiment a bit with the above (very simple!) handler first to get a hang of what gets sent. Put it behind a simple form (which you can just write the HTML for and keep in a file on your filesystem) and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you for the information!
So to clarify the crux of my situation:

I have an IRC bot & a Discord bot, both running separately on TCL.
If I set this TCL web-server up as another separate program (which seems to be the only way?), is there a way for me to execute procedures within the bots, based on the HTTP requests I receive on the web-server? Or can I launch the web-server within one of the bots?

That'd be the main point of the thing; To receive a request from Twitch API and then for example output information to an IRC channel or a Discord text channel.